# HTML Form actions for proxied link to API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, express

So I have a form working fine like this

```
  <form method="POST" action='http://localhost:3000/newRecord'>
```

What I'd like to do is to have the action be only action='/newRecord'. I used to do this in React by going into package.json and setting "proxy": 'localhost:3000' but this is not working in my plain index.js file. What;s going on?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't running the React development server with the built-in proxy. You aren't running the JavaScript preprocessor. You are submitting data with a regular form and not JavaScript.

Configuration settings don't do anything if there is no software set up to handle them.

Comment: Okay that's what I figured, but how can I achieve the same effect without React dev server and all?

Comment: Write a proxy server. Write some JavaScript to search form `action` attributes and rewrite the URLs.